# Максимальное количество чисел из массива, сумма которых не превосходит K

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Дан массив `A` из `N` натуральных чисел. Нужно найти размер подмассива `A` максимальной длины, сумма элементов которого не превосходит `K`.

Пример:

```
A = [1, 4, 2, 3]
K = 6

Ответ: 3 (подмассив [1, 2, 3])
```

Правильно ли я думаю, что если отсортировать массив, то ответом будет количество первых элементов массива, сумма которых не превосходит `К`? И есть ли способ получше?

Comment: Вроде бы так, но только если у вас не спрашивают подмассив как отрезок последовательных элементов имеющегося массива - тогда в вашем случае это будет 2 (элементы 4, 2). Тогда это совсем другая задача.

Comment: Последовательность не важна. Я написал комментарий к ответу @ioann sys, с попыткой доказательства правильности решения, но мог ошибиться в рассуждениях. Буду благодарен, если посмотрите.

Comment: @НиколайПетров, да, все правильно. Берете такой подмассив, заменяете в нем любой элемент на какой-то другой из исходного массива - сумма увеличивается, поскольку в вашем подмассиве уже собраны минимальные элементы. Только вот сумма все еще может остаться меньше K, то есть такой подмассив может быть не один. Тогда логичнее ставить задачу о длине, поскольку длина у них будет одинакова, так как заменой одного из элементов на больший длину увеличить нельзя, только уменьшить или сохранить, и такой подмассив уже не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваша интерпретация постановки задачи действительно верна, то предложенный вам алгоритм - верен. Однако можно предложить более эффективное решение.

Вы можете применить обыкновенный алгоритм quick sort с дополнительной модификацией.

- Если после выполнения partitioning оказывается, что сумма элементов в левой (меньшей) части массива *не меньше* чем `K`, то правая часть массива вас больше не интересует и тратить время на дальнейшую сортировку *правой* части никакого смысла нет.
- В случае же, когда сумма элементов в левой (меньшей) части массива *меньше* чем `K`, вы сразу знаете, что *все* элементы левой части заведомо входят в искомый подмассив и тратить время на дальнейшую сортировку *левой* части никакого смысла нет.

Это та же самая стратегия, по которой работает классический алгоритм поиска "k наименьших элементов", с той только разницей, что вы ищете не k наименьших элементов, а неизвестное число наименьших элементов, чья сумма не превосходит `K`.

Таким образом на каждом уровне рекурсивного подразбиения вам нужно выполнять рекурсивный вызов только для одной половины подразбиения, в то время как вторая половина либо полностью игнорируется, либо просто целиком отправляется на выход (и затем игнорируется). Такой алгоритм должен легко допускать истинно циклическую реализацию, без использования стека.

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ, хорошая оптимизация. Я просто сомневался, что мои рассужения насчет сортировки верные.

Answer (score 0):

Может, тут подразумевается решение без сортировки?

Типа, может быть и несколько подмассивов, но разной длины (пример не удачный :) три подмассива одинаковой длины).

subArray[0] {1, 4}; subArray[1] {4, 2}; subArray[2] {2, 3};

Comment: Просто нужно найти максимальное количество чисел из массива, сумма которых не превосходит K. Не важно, какие это числа и в какой последовательности они идут. Без сортировки я не придумал алгоритма, сложность которого меньше O(n*log n). Но и не могу доказать правильность решения с сортировкой. Первое, что приходит в голову: Если массив А отсортирован, и мы знаем, что сумма первых i элементов не превосходит K, а сумма первых i+1 элементов больше K, то не найдется такого элемента среди первых i элементов, который можно заменить больше чем одним элементом из подмассива А[i+1:], чтобы сумма была <K

Comment: Есть ли ошибка в моих рассуждениях?